# Помогите понять, где в моём коде ошибка

Tags: c, алгоритм

Часа 3 бился над простым кодом, никак не пойму, где там ошибка. Код вырван из проекта, так что может показаться странным ). В массиве Pred [ ] первое число - буква 'И' в кодировке CP866. В первом if проверяется вхождение в диапазон русских букв даной кодировки. Во втором if - проверка на то, что символ не является буквой русского алфавита. Проблема в том, что условие первоого if по непонятным для меня причинам не выполняется. Подскажите, почему условие первого if не выполняется (а по-моему, должно), а второго выполняется?

```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main(int argc, char **argv)
   {
      char  Pred [ ] = { 0x88, 0 };
      char  * TekPred = Pred;
      char ** AdrTekPred;
      char  ImxIdent [256] = { 0 };
      char * AdrTekSimv = NULL;
      char  TekSimv;

      AdrTekPred = & TekPred;
      AdrTekSimv = * AdrTekPred;
      TekSimv = * AdrTekSimv;
      int  FlgPervRaz = 1;

      if  (  ( ( (TekSimv>=0x80) && (TekSimv<=0xAF) ) || ( (TekSimv>=0xE0) && (TekSimv<=0xF1) )  )  &&  FlgPervRaz  == 1  )
      {
         ImxIdent [ 0 ] = TekSimv;
         printf ( "\nPrisvaivanie proizowlo pravil'no." );
      }

      printf ( "\nTekSimv = %c,  ImxIdent [ 0 ] = %c\n", TekSimv, ImxIdent [ 0 ] );

      if (  (  ! ( ( (TekSimv>=0x80) && (TekSimv<=0xAF) ) || ( (TekSimv>=0xE0) && (TekSimv<=0xF1) )  )  )  &&  FlgPervRaz  == 1  )
      {
         printf ( "Nevernoe prisvaivanie.");
         return  0;
      }

      return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Потому что char — это (обычно) число от -128 до 127, а 0x88 — это аж 136, и char никогда не может иметь значение 136, потому что максимум 127 на большинстве систем

Comment: И, кстати, вам компилятор должен был написать соответствующее предупреждение. Вы не читаете предупреждения компилятора или не включили их?

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо за подсказку, теперь заработало как надо ). А компилятор мой предупреждений не давал. Пользуюсь CodeBlocks.

Comment: CodeBlocks это не компилятор

Comment: Вы правы, это IDE. Автоматически написал "компилятор".

Comment: Откройте настройки компилятора, включите там `-Wall` и `-Wextra`. А на счет компилятора - если вы на Windows, то CodeBlocks скорее всего сама установила какую-то старую версию GCC.

Comment: @andreymal, разве он автоматически не переведёт в int при сравнении? По-моему там работает правило integer promotion, а поскольку число знаковое, то старшие биты будут установлены соответственно, и условие не выполнится.

Comment: @0andriy а какой толк от перевода в int, если число в памяти порезалось ещё задолго до сравнения?

Comment: @andreymal, оно не порезалось.

Comment: @0andriy покажите мне пример, как в коде `char TekSimv; TekSimv = * AdrTekSimv;` может поместиться число 136, пожалуйста?

Comment: @andreymal Там -120, очевидно. Не вижу обрезания. Вот когда найдёте архитектуру, где char не может содержать 8 бит, тогда и поговорим :)

Comment: @0andriy вам не кажется, что -120 и 136 — это, мягко говоря, разные числа? Неужели мне придётся вам читать лекцию про то, что старший бит в дополнительном коде указывает на знак числа?

Comment: @andreymal так вам бы про разрядность шины данных вначале, про знак я выше писал. Никаких **порезалось** тут и в помине нет.

Comment: @0andriy всё очень даже порезалось, потому что старший бит ушёл на знак и перестал быть частью значения числа. Под число осталось 7 остальных бит.